# Referencing unopened excel workbooks in a formula returns a #REF! error

Tags: excel, formula

I created a directory in Sharepoint with many workbooks where my team inserts the information I need to create a dashboard.

To do this, I am trying to create (in another file) a table that uses an index/match formula to retrieve the data I need. 
It works just fine, except if I open the  workbook without the referenced workbook being opened the formula throws an error and all rows returns `#REF!`.

How Do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of referencing the workbook as

```
='[Filename.xlsx]Sheet1'!$H$1
```

Refer it with the entire path

```
='C:\Users\[Filename.xlsx]Sheet1'!$H$1
```